# Batch file that would delete all the files and folders that the batch file is located in?

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, directory, delete-file

Is it possible to make a batch file that would delete all the files and folders that the batch file is located in?

I.E: I place the batch file into folder with useless files, I run it, and it deletes all the files and folders in that folder.

Then I can just move the batch file to another folder and do the same there...

Would really help me out! I need this to delete temporary files on other people's computers before installing new files... But sadly I am not very familiar with batch.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Have you made any attempt at all?  You should post your attempt(code) first and if you can't get it to work, then we will help you.  If you don't know anything about batch files then you should learn about them first (i.e. Google) before putting code on user's machines that you can't support.

Comment: Do you care about hidden files? This seems like a one-line rmdir or del command should do just fine.

Comment: what about the very same batch file, should it be erased as well?

Comment: @Pa It doesn't matter, likely, yes. If it isn't possible, it's not a big deal! I can do it through my program just by typing out one line of code :)

Comment: @rickS No man :( I know how to create batch files... I know a few CMD commands, but I never learnt much about batch itself.

Comment: @ben I am pretty sure there will be no hidden files, in the folders, where this batch file will end up in :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all the files in the current directory except your batch file use:

```
echo off
for %%i in (*.*) do if not "%%i"=="del.bat" del /q "%%i"
```

Note that the "del.bat" is the name of the batch file you save this as.

As another side note you could add after the del /q the "/p" command to make this a little bit safer. That way it will prompt you before deleting each file.

To remove everything in the folder including the .bat file use

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

To remove everything including folders except the .bat file use

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || if not "%%i"=="del.bat" del "%%i" /s/q)
```

Where del.bat is your batch file name.

Comment: Man thanks a lot! But one little problem, I need it to delete all the folders too :o Is that possible?

Comment: Copy the for loop, but use `rmdir /S` instead of `del` and `*` instead of `*.*` and I think it will delete all folders as well.

Comment: Added a change to remove all files from the folder including the batch file itself.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this: echo off
for %%i in (*) do if not "%%i"=="del.bat" rmdir /S "%%i"... Now when I run it, a CMD opens, gives me the current directory, and asks "Are you sure Y/N" - I press "Y", the CMD goes away, but nothing happens!

Comment: @RandyRakestraw Thanks man! You deserve a medal... no, 2 medals :) OR 3 :P You helped me a lot :)